# Offset selection in Excel from Access

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I'm creating an Excel file from data in an Access database.

All I'm currently trying to do is offset a selection I've made in Excel from Access, and I keep receiving errors.

`ExcelWS.Range(Range("H6"), Range("H6").End(xlDown)).Offset(0, -1).Select`

ExcelWS is an Excel. Worksheet object.

My goal is to select from G6 to the end of the workbook. However, not every cell in column G is populated, so a simple End(xlDown) from cell G6 only takes me part way through the file. That being said, all cells in column H are populated, so I'm able to do an End(xlDown) from cell H6. From there, I want to move my selection one to the left, giving me the desired range in column G selected.

The above code is a product of about 2hrs of googling, and trying tons of different combinations of similar code. However, I'm still receiving an error.

> Run-time error '1004':
>
> Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed

The odd thing is that 1/10 times, I'll receive the desire results. The rest of the time I receive the above error.

I feel as though my issue has something to do with running that line of code from Access, however that's currently my only way of completing this task as I have other things that rely on being able to do it from Access.

Any help would be appreciated, and if there's any more info I can give I'll try my best.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run `Select` the sheet shoudl be active/ in -focus.

So you ned to set foucus to sheet.

```
ExcelWS.Activate
ExcelWS.Range(Range("H6"), Range("H6").End(xlDown)).Offset(0, -1).Select
```

Simalarly, to make the seet in-focus, your workbook needs to be active/ infocus.

Try to avoid  `Select` as much as possible. Also fully qualify the names.

```
 Dim rngTest as Range
 Set rngTest= ExcelWS.Range(ExcelWS.Range("H6"), ExcelWS.Range("H6").End(xlDown)).Offset(0, -1)
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the info. I ended up "butchering" the code you gave me a little bit to find what worked, as either solution on it's own wasn't quite what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @cyboashu, I was able to get it working.

I took the examples he gave me and mushed them together to make it do what I wanted.

I realized after posting the question that it was working every other time, consistently.

Anyway, the code I used is

```
Dim ExcelR1 As Range
Set ExcelR1 = ExcelWS.Range(ExcelWS.Range("H6"), ExcelWS.Range("H6").End(xlDown)).Offset(0, -1)
ExcelR1.Activate
```